# How to calculate alternating sum of digits of an integer in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

> A number is divisible by 11 if its alternating sum of digits is
>   divisible by 11.

So, e.g. if number is `1595`, `+1 -5 +9 -5 == 0`, so 1595 is divisible by 11. How to implement such a sum? Here is my solution, but it's too complex and works only if the number of digits is even.

```
my $number = 1595;
say [+] $number.comb.map({$^a - $^b});
```

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: One nit about your solution (which I like, BTW):  If the number would have an odd number of digits, it will fail with `Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1`.  You can fix this by changing the signature to the block: `say [+] "15956".comb.map(-> $a, $b = 0 {$a - $b}); # 6`

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thanks! I felt I should have given $^b a default value, but didn't know how to do it.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Then probably the following is a bit easier, since it doesn't require default. :) `say [+] 15956.comb.kv.map({ $^b * (-1) ** $^a})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
say [+] 1595.comb >>*>> (1,-1)
```

Similar to the Z* version but using the hyper meta operator looping effect on the right hand side (if the left hand side has less than 2 digits you are fine).

Comment: Probably, that's the best solution!

Answer (score 6):

```
say [+] 1595.comb Z* (1, -1, 1 ... *)
```

To break it down: .comb returns a list of characters, and Z* multiplies that list element-wise with the sequence on the RHS.

This sequence is a geometric sequence, which the `...` series operator can deduce from the three elements. Since the zip operator `Z` stops at the shortest sequence, we don't have to take care to terminate the sequence on the RHS.

Another way to write the same thing is:

```
say [+] 1595.comb Z* (1, -* ... *)
```

Where `-*` is the explicit negation of the previous value, applied to the initial element to generate the next one.

You could also write that as

```
say [+] 1595.comb Z* (1, &prefix:<-> ... *)
```

Comment: Oh, I felt that there should be an elegant solution! Didn't know how to implement `1, -1, 1...`, it's very useful!

Answer (score 5):

The cross that Moritz uses is interesting (and quite pleasing) but you can also take chunks of a list. This is close to what you were trying initially. I think you were going toward `rotor`:

```
my $number = 1595;
say  [+] $number.comb.rotor(2, :partial).map: { $^a.[0] - ($^a.[1] // 0) }
```

Notice that you get one argument to your block. That's the list. It's a bit ugly because the odd digit case makes `$^a.[1]` `Nil` which would give a warning.

Now that I've played with this a bit more I handle that with a signature so I can give `$b` a default. This is much better:

```
my $number = 1595;
say  [+] $number
    .comb
    .rotor(2, :partial)
    .map: -> ( $a, $b = 0 ) { $a - $b }
```

But you don't even need the `rotor` because the `map` will grab as many positional parameters as it needs (h/t to timotimo in the comments). This means you were really close and merely missed the signature:

```
my $number = 1595;
say  [+] $number
    .comb
    .map: -> ( $a, $b = 0 ) { $a - $b }
```

The solution you have in the comment doesn't quite work for the odd number of digits cases:

```
say [+] $number.comb.rotor(2, :partial).map({[-] $_});
```

And, I know this problem wasn't really about divisors but I'm quite pleased that Perl 6 has a "divisible by" operator, the `%%`:

```
$ perl6
> 121 %% 11
True
> 122 %% 11
False
> 1595 %% 11
True
> 1596 %% 11
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it! Then what about the following solution? `say [+] $number.comb.rotor(2, :partial).map({[-] $_}`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was wrong: `[-] (1)` gives `-1` (I was sure it would be `1`).

Comment: there is no need to use `.rotor(2, :partial).map(($a, $b = 0) -> {})` here, just using `.map(-> $a, $b = 0 { })` should behave the same way.

Comment: @timotimo At least it was just for me to learn about the `rotor`. :)

Comment: @briandfoy Here's my new variant, hope it's correct. `say [+] 15956.comb.kv.map({ $^b * (-1) ** $^a})`

Comment: @briandfoy This also works :) `say [+] 15956.comb.kv.map( (-1) ** * * *)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.

```
say [+] 15956.comb.kv.map( (-1) ** * * * ); # 6
```

And a more explicit version.

```
say [+] 15956.comb.kv.map({ $^b * (-1) ** $^a }); # 6
```

**UPD**: Yet another solution.

```
say - [+] 15956.comb(2)>>.comb.map({[R-] $_}); # 6
```

Comment:  the math. Another more explicit version: `say [+] 15956.comb.pairs».&{ (-1) ** .key * .value }`. Whereas `.kv` returns a list of 2 element lists, `.pairs` returns a list of `Pair`s. Whereas `.map` lazily consumes the list on its left by passing N elements at a time to the operation on its right, `»` (`>>` in ASCII) eagerly consumes the list on its left by running the operation on its right on each single element in the list, doing so in parallel (on multiple cores, or a GPU, or using some other [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) approach) if the compiler decides to do so.

Comment: @raiph Thanks! Could you please explain the meaning of `.&`? The [link for .& in docs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/.&) seems to be broken. There are some [explanations here](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Hyper_Operators), but I will not pretend that I understand how it works. :)

Comment: @EugeneBarsky The postfix `.` indicates a method call. The "inline method" is `&{...}`. This is a closure that will be passed a single argument, the invocant. The syntax is `.&{...}` rather than just `.{...}` because the latter is a hash subscript, the same as a postfix (actually postcircumfix) `{...}` without the `.`. The disambiguating character is `&` because the latter is the appropriate sigil (it indicates a routine).